# Python returning map object

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, numpy-ndarray

I'm fairly new to python and following Machine Learning In Python book. In an example there I have

```
min(datMat[:,0])
```

which is supposed to return

```
 matrix([[-5.379713]])
```

But what I get is

```
 matrix([[<map object at 0x000002130BF3E240>]], dtype=object)
```

and when I include this in code

```
rangeJ = float(max(dataSet[:,j]) - minJ)
```

I get the error "TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'map' and 'map'".

This is the code I'm using to generate dataMat

```
def loadDataSet(fileName):
    dataMat = []
    fr = open(fileName)
    for line in fr.readlines():
       curLine = line.strip().split('\t')
       fltLine = map(float,curLine)
       dataMat.append(fltLine)
   return dataMat
```

I'm having a hard time figuring this out. Any help would be great!!

Comment: Sorry, I don't know the answer to your problem, but I suspect this could be a Python 2 vs Python 3 issue, since the behaviour of `map` changed. Which version are you using?

Comment: python 3.. I also guessed that But having a hard time solving the issue

Comment: Whatever code you are using to generate `datMat` is likely causing the problem here. We will need more information to help you debug.

Comment: Hi.. Edited the question

Comment: That's better. The problem's obvious once we can see the offending code. ;)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As suggested was likely in the comment by PM 2Ring, your book seems be using Python 2 while you are using Python 3. The `map` function returns a list in Python 2, but in Python 3 it returns a map object unless you explicitly convert it to a list. You should be able to make your code work by changing this line:

```
fltLine = map(float,curLine)
```

To:

```
fltLine = list(map(float,curLine))
```